# How to use Cucumber in forms with custom labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'm trying to learn how to use cucumber and got this issue:

I have a form that as:

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "Nome" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
```

And in my cucumber feature I have:

```
  And I fill in "name" with "Reitoria do Porto"
```

This make the test fail with:

```
And I fill in "name" with "Reitoria do Porto"       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34
      Could not find field: "name" (Webrat::NotFoundError)
      (eval):2:in `fill_in'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35:in `/^(?:|I )fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/'
      features/manage_institutions.feature:10:in `And I fill in "name" with "Reitoria do Porto"'
```

However if I just make the form like this:

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
```

The test passes.

How can I keep my custom label name and make the test pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webrat uses the label text to locate the field to fill in. In your first example, are you not setting this label to "Nome"?

Does `And I fill in "Nome" with "Reitoria do Porto"` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the field name as it appears in HTML. So if the model `name`belongs to is lets say `User`than you should be able to access it via

> And I fill in "user_name" with "Reitoria do Porto"

If in doubt, just have a look at the generated HTML code and take the field name from there.